# How can I change the navigation bar to the three-dots mode?

Tags: android

I want to set the navigation bar to the three-dots look, like:
[image]

Android Developers site shows how to completely remove the navbar (the fullscreen mode), but doesn't show how to enable this mode.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to this [document](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/dim.html) .

Basically, call this method in the `onCreate`, just before `setContentView`

```
// This example uses decor view, but you can use any visible view.
View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

When you need to reveal the bars programmatically, clear the flags like below:

```
View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
// Calling setSystemUiVisibility() with a value of 0 clears
// all flags.
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(0);
```